# Disable or workaround to iPad waking up and Pen is magnetically attached

Tags: ipad, sleep-wake, apple-pencil

So I just upgraded my old iPad which supported pen 1.0 to new iPad Air with pen 2.0 which is now magnetically attached to the side

now my issue is that the magnets are not super strong so when I insert the iPad to my backpack when the Pen is magnetically attached to the side of it, every minor movement slides the pen a little out not completely but enough for it to disconnect and reconnect back with the magnets.

Thats causes the screen to wake up.

I know it may sound silly but it actually happens way too many times even while I'm still holding it and then my fingers press stuffs accidentally.

Is there a way to disable that feature that when the pen is charging (attached magnetically to the side) the screen will not wake up?

I disabled "Tap to Wake" but that's not it,

or perhaps any workaround to avoid that?

b.t.w I go caseless.

Answer (score 1):

There’s no way to disable this currently. Placing the pencil in a holder away from the magnets is the only workaround.